# How to populate interface for existing object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface:

```
struct result {
  virtual ~result() = 0;
  virtual auto getName() -> std::string = 0;

  protected:
    result() = default;
    result(const result &) = default;
    auto operator=(const result &) -> result & = default;
}
```

and an implementation:

```
struct abstract_result : public result {
  auto getName() -> std::string override;
  std::string m_name;
}
```

I'm currently using an instance of `abstract_result` within my code to be populated by a number of algorithms but I want the end user to receive a pointer to the interface so I can hide the implementation.

How can I turn an instance of `abstract_result` into a `std::unique_ptr<result>`?

Comment: I dont' think there is any other solution than copy construction from stack to heap by `make_unique` or just create object on heap in first place

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<result> p(new abstract_result)` will do it.   Bear in mind that the destructor of `std::unique_ptr`, by default, assumes the contained pointer points at an object created by operator `new`, and destroys it using operator `delete`.

Comment: @bartop so move a std::unique_ptr<abstract_result> into a std::unique_ptr<result>?

Comment: @Peter The instance of abstract_result is already populated.

Comment: @ruipacheco Then clone it using operator `new`, and store the address of the clone in the `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is pretty similar to what @user463035818 says, but with the populated structure, i.e.:

```
std::unique_ptr<result> pointer_to_result {&my_populated_abstract_result };
```

And this is fine since, again, an `abstract_result` is-a `result`. But you **might not want to do this at all** if your `my_populated_abstract_result` is not dynamically allocated. std::unique_ptr is not generally intended for use with objects on the stack (e.g. local variables). If `my_populated_abstract_result` is a local variable - **don't put in a `unique_ptr` at all** (nor in an `std::shared_ptr`), and don't try to hold on to it once  `my_populated_abstract_result` goes out of scope.

PS :

- Doesn't it make more sense for the pure-virtual base class to be called `abstract_result`, with the concrete classes being `foo_result`, `bar_result`, `baz_result`?
- Perhaps it's a good idea to use a namespace if you really have a lot of names with `_result` in them? That way you'll have `result::abstract` (or `result::base`) and then `result::foo`, `result::bar`, `result::baz`.

Comment: @ruipacheco: See my naming convention notes too.

Answer (score 3):

An `abstract_result` is-a `result` (btw your naming seems to be the wrong way around) so a pointer to a `abstract_result` is-a pointer to a `result`. So you just need to construct the `unique_ptr`, eg

```
auto x = unique_ptr<result>(new abstract_result());
```

In case the instance is on the stack and you are worried about `unique_ptr` trying to delete an instance with automaitc storage, you can use a deleter that does nothing, as in

```
template <typename T>
struct no_deleter {
    void operator()(T*){}
};

abstract_result x;
std::unique_ptr<result> x_ptr{ &x, no_deleter<result>() };
```

However, in that case I wonder why you want to use a `unique_ptr` in the first place. There is nothing wrong about using raw pointers as long as they do not own the object (ie whoever holds the pointer is not responsible for deleting the object), while a `unique_ptr` is usually meant to own the object it points to.

**PS**

I have to admit that I dont fully understand what is your problem...

> but I want to turn a populated instance of abstract_result into a
>   pointer to result

As mentioned above, a pointer to a `abstract_result` is (sloppy-speaking) already a pointer to a `result`. A simpler example:

```
abstract_result x;
result* pointer_to_result = &x;
```

Comment: `So you just need to construct the unique_ptr` - but I want to turn a populated instance of  `abstract_result` into a pointer to result.

Comment: @ruipacheco it is unclear what you think is the problem. If `x` is the object then `&x` is a pointer to the object (sorry there was a typo in my example)

Comment: @ruipacheco if this doesnt help, please add some code to your question of what you would like to write but does not work together with the error messages you get

Comment: Basically the implementation of a library uses `abstract_result` but the end user uses `result` which given the way C++ works should be a `std::unique_ptr<result>`.

Comment: If OP's `abstract_result` is on the stack, they shouldn't be passing it around in a `unique_ptr`, but by reference or plain non-owning pointer.

Comment: @einpoklum completely agree, maybe my note on that could be more clear. The thing is that I didnt really understand what is the problem so tried to cover also the possiblity that it is on the stack but for some reason it needs to be a `unique_ptr`